# Kodi add-on crashing on window.removeControl()

Tags: python, kodi

I'm developing a Kodi add-on that uses a custom overlay. It's almost completely working now, except for one runtime error I get every time I start a video, after reaching 5 seconds in the video ("Error Contents: Control does not exist in window"). Here's the code for addon.py below:

```
import xbmc, xbmcaddon, xbmcgui, os
ADDON = xbmcaddon.Addon()
addonpath = ADDON.getAddonInfo('path')

class OverlayBackground(object):
   def __init__(self):
      self.showing = False
      self.window = xbmcgui.Window()
      origin_x = 0
      origin_y = 0
      window_w = self.window.getWidth()
      window_h = self.window.getHeight()
      self._background = xbmcgui.ControlImage(origin_x, origin_y, window_w, window_h, os.path.join(addonpath,"resources","skins","default","media","background.png"))
   def show(self):
      self.showing=True
      self.window.addControl(self._background)
   def hide(self):
      self.showing=False
      self.window.removeControl(self._background)
   def _close(self):
      if self.showing:
         self.hide()
      else:
         pass
      try:
         self.window.clearProperties()
      except: pass

if (__name__ == '__main__'):
   monitor = xbmc.Monitor()
   while not monitor.abortRequested():
      if xbmc.Player().isPlaying():
         theOverlay = OverlayBackground()
         if(xbmc.Player().getTime() < 5):
            theOverlay.show()
         else:
            theOverlay.hide()
         xbmc.sleep(1000)
```

The error came from "self.window.removeControl(self._background)", as mentioned in this [paste bin](https://paste.kodi.tv/meduserezi.kodi). It seems odd, because I'm sure that the control was added prior to running this command, so I'm not sure what's causing this command to crash the add-on.

I tried asking over in the Kodi forums for help, and was told that I need to get the ID of the player that I'm controlling (and linked to [the documentation for Control](https://romanvm.github.io/Kodistubs/_modules/xbmcgui.html#Control)), but I'm not sure how to implement that, even after researching the documentation extensively.

I would highly appreciate any clarification on this. Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to check if the overlay already removed

```
   def show(self):
      if not self.showing:
          self.showing=True
          self.window.addControl(self._background)
   def hide(self):
      if self.showing:
          self.showing=False
          self.window.removeControl(self._background)
```